# How to Place the swiper at the far left of the Screen - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to place this Swiper at the far left of the screen, such that it doesn't take the whole screen but it docks at the left. The package places it at the center which I don't want. How can I place it there

I am using `card_swiper: ^3.0.1`

Here is the code

```
    class SpacesHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  const SpacesHeader({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Beevers Sacco",
              style: sfBold.copyWith(
                  fontSize: Dimensions.sizeUltraLarge - 5, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: Dimensions.sizeMicroSmall),
            Text(
              "The next Spaces meeting will be on\n12th of June 2021",
              style: sfRegular.copyWith(
                  fontSize: Dimensions.sizeDefault, color: kDarkGray),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: Dimensions.sizeUltraLarge),
            SizedBox(
                height: 150,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                        left: 0,
                        child: Swiper(
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: kPremium,
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.sizeSmall),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          axisDirection: AxisDirection.right,
                          itemCount: 10,
                          itemWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                          itemHeight: 150.0,
                          layout: SwiperLayout.STACK,
                        )),
                  ],
                ))
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Here is the image
[image: Move the orange slider to the far left, not center but should not cover whole screen]

Comment: Can you show any image representation for the of what you are getting and what you are want to achieve

Comment: @SagarAcharya I've uploaded image

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your widget with `Stack` and replace your `Positioned` widget instead of `Align` widget. Update as yourself.

```
  Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        left: 3, // you can also add top, right, and bottom as well
        child: Swiper(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0xFFFFC140),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
            );
          },
          axisDirection: AxisDirection.right,
          itemCount: 10,
          itemWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
          itemHeight: 150.0,
          layout: SwiperLayout.STACK,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

I've tried this kind of many more.

```
class _TestCardSwiperState extends State<TestCardSwiper> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  final SwiperController _swiperController = SwiperController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Card Swiper"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 150,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
                      if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
                        _swiperController.previous();
                      } else if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
                        _swiperController.next();
                      }
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                      height: 150,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned.fill(
                  child: Swiper(
                    controller: _swiperController,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: const Color(0xFFFFC140),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    axisDirection: AxisDirection.right,
                    itemCount: 10,
                    itemWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                    itemHeight: 150.0,
                    layout: SwiperLayout.STACK,
                    onIndexChanged: (index) {
                      setState(() {
                        currentIndex = index;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          // GestureDetector(
          //   onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
          //     if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
          //       _swiperController.previous();
          //     } else if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
          //       _swiperController.next();
          //     }
          //   },
          //   child: SizedBox(
          //     height: 150,
          //     child: Swiper(
          //       controller: _swiperController,
          //       itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          //         return Container(
          //           decoration: BoxDecoration(
          //             color: const Color(0xFFFFC140),
          //             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          //           ),
          //         );
          //       },
          //       axisDirection: AxisDirection.right,
          //       itemCount: 10,
          //       itemWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
          //       itemHeight: 150.0,
          //       layout: SwiperLayout.STACK,
          //       onIndexChanged: (index) {
          //         setState(() {
          //           currentIndex = index;
          //         });
          //       },
          //     ),
          //   ),
          // ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for this, problem with this is, it doesn't swipe and doesn't show the stack

Comment: It works very well. If you still can't solve the problem then you can share your code. I will try to solve it. I already achieved similar to your image.

Comment: I have edited the code on the question, kindly check

Comment: I'm sorry for you brother. I tried it for at least 4-6 hours. Their package has this limitation (in axisDirection property) that's why we can't achieve it. You may try with pageview widget. Though, at that time you've to make your custom swiper widget.

Comment: Thanks brother. I appreciate the effort. Lemme just see a way around it. Blessed